# Laravel - Find out if the row was inserted or updated

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to get either a `1` (the record was inserted) or a `2` (the record was updated). How can this be done using Laravel? I can't find any information about this in their documentation.

```
DB::insert('insert into ratings
    (owner_id, game_id, rating) values (?, ?, ?)
    on duplicate key update rating = values(rating)',
    [
        (int)$body['user'], (int)$gameId, (int)$body['amount']
    ]);
```

I know I can get pdo like this:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

but I don't think that helps...

Comment: Maybe you could check last insert id before and after?

Comment: I would like to accomplish this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html -> `With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.`

Comment: Can you store the output of `DB::insert()` in a variable and dump it, to see if that tells you? E.g. `$output = DB::insert(...); dd($output);`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the function `affectingStatement` which seems to return the number of affected rows...

```
$res = DB::affectingStatement('insert into ratings
(owner_id, game_id, rating) values (?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update rating = values(rating)', [
    (int)$body['user'], 
    (int)$gameId, 
    (int)$body['amount']
]);
```

For me, this was returning 2 when a row updates, 1 when a row is inserted, and 0 on failure as expected.